# FC15 yum fedora repo recovery

Tags: fedora, yum

I have lost all files under /etc/yum.repos.d/ and need a source or quick method for recovery.

kernel version : 2.6.43.8-1.fc15.i686 / Fedora 15 Lovelock yum version : yum-3.2.29-9.fc15.noarch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the releases that have ever been are available here off of the Fedora Project's website:

- https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/

Fedora 15 is here:

- https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/15/Fedora/

Comment: I've tried to install yum from one of the packages provide on Fedora Project's archive.   What I find is that an rpm install does nothing to re-build the original yum files/paths.   If I try to run yum I get the following :

CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Accidental deletion of /etc/yum.conf and /etc/yum.repos.d/ folders.  I have since been able to install yum.repos.d/ by forcing rpm install with no dependency check, but still need a way to load the default repos under etc/yum.repos.d/ and yum.conf.

Comment: restored /etc/yum.conf using rpm --force --nodeps --replacepkgs.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 15 is *long* out of any kind of support. Do yourself a favor and install a newer version, or (if long term stability is required) migrate to latest CentOS.

Comment: That's like dangling the carrot in front of someone who obviously lacks a bit of self control (hence my existing problem).   Thanks for the suggestion anyway; I'm almost finished downloading the debian iso

Comment: @Aardvark - ouch, don't go to Debian, stay w/ Fedora.

Comment: Attempted to install multiple distros last night, but whatever method I used cd/dvd/usb all seemed non-bootable...  I plan on settling on Centos, more for popularity in the development community (at least as indicated by indeed.com)

Answer (score 0):

[question resolution on fedoraproject](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/42211/fc15-yum-fedora-repo-recovery/)

> Try this if possible ...
>
> wget
>
> archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/15/Fedorai386/os/Packages/fedora-release-15-1.noarch.rpm
>
> rpm --force -Uvh fedora-release-15.1.noarch.rpm
>
> This should restore all of the original repository files under
>   /etc/yum.repos.d/

That seemed to do it; apparently I was just referencing the wrong installing package, and the only problem I encountered was with the posted URL missing trailing slash after 15/Fedora and a dependency error which was resolved with --nodeps options.
I appreciate everyone's help on this issue

**encountered a few more issues:**

[root@Beelzebub etc]# yum check

Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/blacklist.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin blacklist
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/refresh-packagekit.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin refresh-packagekit
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/whiteout.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin whiteout
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto
fedora-release-15-1.noarch has missing requires of fedora-release-rawhide = ('0', '15', '1')
yum-3.2.29-9.fc15.noarch is a duplicate with yum-3.2.29-4.fc15.noarch
yum-langpacks-0.2.4-2.fc15.noarch is a duplicate with yum-langpacks-0.2.2-1.fc15.noarch
yum-utils-1.1.31-2.fc15.noarch is a duplicate with yum-utils-1.1.30-2.fc15.noarch

Error: check all

**update** : reinstalled rawhide successfully
rpm -iUvh 
https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/15/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/fedora-release-rawhide-15-1.noarch.rpm

**update** : anaconda-yum-plugins contains all missing configuration files; still unsure about removing duplicates ...

**update** : yum reinstall seems to take care of the duplicate warnings